# Time Machine attempts to inherit backup from wrong Mac

Tags: time-machine, migration

Most people seem to want to get their new Mac to inherit their old Mac's backup. I seem to have the opposite problem.

I have a person who used Migration Assistant to move from a Mac mini to a laptop. I wiped and repurposed the mini, and used Time Machine to make a fresh backup image of it on an AFP server running FreeNAS 9.2. What's curious is, when the laptop creates a new Time Machine backup on the same server, I'm asked if I want to inherit the new backup image made by the mini.

Clearly there's still something in the migrated system on the laptop left over from the Mac mini that's causing it to associate itself with the mini's backup. I've confirmed that the value of com.apple.backupd.HostUUID in the com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist file of the mini's backup matches the mini's hardware UUID from `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType`, which differs from the laptop's hardware UUID.

Any ideas why Time Machine thinks it's still installed on the older Mac?